# Symfony2/Doctrine2 relation same object twice

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.2

I have a problem with doctrine entity mapping.
Have a basic user entity and I want to create a Friend entity, what made up from two foreign key to the user table, the first owner of the friendship and the other.
I tried to do it in this way ( yaml ), the entities are generated the correct way, but when I create the DB with doctrine scheme update, it has a totally different result.

The user entity:

```
..\..\Entity\User:
type:  entity
uniqueConstraints:
    usernameCanonical:
        columns: usernameCanonical
    emailCanonical:
        columns: emailCanonical
oneToMany:
    owners:
        targetEntity: Friend
        mappedBy: owner
    friends:
        targetEntity: Friend
        mappedBy: friend
```

And the friend entity:

```
..\..\Entity\Friend:
type: entity
table: friend
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [setCreated, setModified]
    preUpdate: [setModified]
manyToOne:
    owner:
        targetEntity: User
        inversedBy: friends
        joinColumn:
            name: user
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: cascade
    friend:
        targetEntity: User
        inversedBy: owners
        joinColumn:
            name: user
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: cascade
```

This should create two foreign to from friend to user, but instead it's create one like:

```
ALTER TABLE friend ADD CONSTRAINT FK_55EEAC618D93D649 FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADEe
```

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you want to do. What do you want in your Friend entity? Couldn't you use self referencing many to many in your user entity?

Comment: Basically map 2 user entity together, but i did like not using mapping, and just two int value, without any foreign key

Comment: You should take a look at the doctrine documentation (ManyToMany Self-referencing): http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing

Comment: Hm, i think this is what i need exactly, i can look into this later. I remember reading that page but didn't see that point. Add as answer cause i think that is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common "Friends" relationship is ManyToMany SelfReferencing doctrine relationship and it's used as an example in the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing)

Comment: Thank you very much, perfect. One quick question, , do you know maybe how can I extend the "friend table" with other field, like a createdAt? or because it's not really an entity, I can't?

Comment: If you want to do that, it's not a ManyToMany relationship but a One To Many Many To One. You have to create a FriendUser entity with 2 User entity as primary composite key and every attribute you want

Comment: Hm, then I don't understand why my original code didn't worked, cause there i have a user and a friend entity, what you suggested.